# Running 7zip command line silently via Python

Tags: python, executable, popen

I've seen plenty of questions regarding the python execution of a .exe file using popen and mentions of using PIPE to stop output of the process. Apologies if my terminology is incorrect, i'm very new to python.

My main aim of this question to to add stdout=PIPE or something similar to prevent any output showing, such as

> "Extracting filename..." This is very bad as some rars are large.

I am trying to run 7zip silently/hidden/quite. So that the entire process can run in the background and not interfere with current on screen operations.

At this time, the current script works fine.

Here is my python code:
**Python 2.7**

Pythonw.exe used to execute code:

pythonw.exe script.py

```
if ".rar" in input_file: 

    subprocess.Popen("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\7z e " + input_file + " -o" + output_dest + " -y")
```

ALl help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe stdout and stderr to your system's null file:

```
import os

with open(os.devnull, 'w') as null:
    subprocess.Popen(['7z', 'e', input_file, '-o', output_dest, '-y'], stdout=null, stderr=null)
```

Comment: NIce, so this can just be added inside the if statement?

Comment: @claw: Sure, why not.

Comment: This is good stuff Blender thanks. Also, do I just use 7z or should I explicitly add the path?

Comment: @claw: You probably need the absolute path if `7z` isn't in your path.

Comment: stdout=null returns syntaxError: invalid syntax pointing at the =

Comment: @claw: Whoops, I put the `]` in the wrong place. Should be fine now.

Comment: you got it! that was the issue. The pboelem im facing now is that the extracted file doesn't appear...im assuming that's being written to null also?