# Running Windows console app silently (suppress console from appearing)

Tags: c, windows-7

I have looked at these posts addressing similar issues: ***[From Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295610/running-7zip-command-line-silently-via-python)*** and ***[Extract Silently](https://superuser.com/questions/331148/7-zip-command-line-extract-silently-quietly)*** and ***[Command Line Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774278/extracting-a-7-zip-file-silently-command-line-option)***

None addresses my specific issue.

I would like to call 7za.exe (and possibly other *console* applications, that by default result in the shell command window) from within an *application written in ANSI C* without the shell prompt window popping up for each call.  From within the Windows command shell, I can append `> nul` to the end of a command line call of 7za, and it suppresses everything, as shown here:

[image]

However, I need to call it in a loop (several hundred times), from a Windows application,  resulting in a constant flicker as Windows launches a shell then kills it when the command is complete.

So far I have tried appending `> nul`, just as I illustrated in the command prompt image above, then using the `system()` command, as well as a modified system command which launches exe in another process:

```
sprintf(command, "7za.exe x -y -o%s %s > nul", filepathUnComp, filepath); 
system(command);
```

***or:***

```
SystemX(command);
```

***Where***  SystemX is defined:

```
int SystemX(command)
{
    STARTUPINFO sj;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pj;
    int exit;

    ZeroMemory( &sj, sizeof(sj) );
    sj.cb = sizeof(sj);
    ZeroMemory( &pj, sizeof(pj) );

    if(CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sj, &pj) == 0)
    {
        //AED_GetErrorMessage(AEDNV_FAILED_CREATE_PROCESS,cmd);
        return -1;
    }

    // Wait until child processes exit.
    WaitForSingleObject( pj.hProcess, IGNORE ); //ingnore signal

    //Get exit code
    GetExitCodeProcess(pj.hProcess, (LPDWORD)(&exit));

    return exit;
}
```

***Both of these methods*** result in the shell prompt window flicker.

Is there a way to run `7za.exe` within an application completely silent, that is, without instantiating the shell command window flicker?

If this is not possible using 7za, I am also open to hearing about other approaches.

Comment: no, it's not possible. you're starting a shell, which will NECESSARILY start the window. `> nul` will do NOTHING to "hide" that window. a window is not "output" of the program, it's where the program's output would GO, if you hadn't redirected it to nul.

Comment: @MarcB  Are you aware of a method, other than 7za (or similar)? I am open to a completely different approach, not locked into using 7za.

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010103/launch-a-program-from-command-line-without-opening-a-new-window, but start itself would run in a shell and cause its own window to be created. basically you'd have to tie into the windows api to start a background process without window.

Comment: If you look around a little, I'm sure you might find some [appropriate `CreateProcess` flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you can use to tell `CreateProcess` to not create any console windows.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - I think your link shows some possibilities.  Thanks

Comment: @MarcB - Thanks, your first explanation helps me to see the real issue.  I Will look into windows APIs.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - DWORD `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` (defined in windows API) added to argument 6 of `CreateProcess` worked.  No command window pops up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be useful to other Windows programmers who need to suppress the shell prompt from appearing when running an executable program that by default launches a shell: (thanks to @Marc B and @ Joachim Pileborg )

Change the original line in the OP `SystemX` code from:

```
 if(CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sj, &pj) == 0);
```

to:

```
 if(CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &sj, &pj) == 0);
```